Driving x27 stepper motors for an automotive gauge cluster
I'm working on a project and have come to realize I may have started with the incorrect setup.  I'd love some feedback on the components I'm using.
Project:
Use CAN bus to receive data from my car with my raspberry pi, then drive small stepper motors in order to accurately position the gauge cluster in real time.
Equipment:
Raspberry pi 4b
RS485 CAN HAT
DRV8833 driver boards
x27 168 stepper motors
Problem:
I've had some difficulty finding people who have a similar setup, which usually leads me to believe I chose the wrong parts.  Everyone seems to be controlling these motors with an Arduino or something similar.  I found a thread of someone attempting a similar setup to mine, where it was suggested that python would not be sufficiently fast or accurate enough for the real-time precise feedback required for this goal.  I've been thinking about returning my raspberry pi and purchasing an Arduino DUE, but before I do I wanted to confirm that the sentiment stated before is true.  If what I want to achieve is possible with my equipment, please let me know as I've already been successful decoding the necessary CAN bus messages with my Rasperry pi, and I just need to position the motors now.  Thank you!!

Pi4 is fast enough and accurate for your project. Only issue maybe startup time and clean shutdown required.

Is there anything you would recommend to ensure a clean shutdown without seeing the code?

I would use a UPS HAT to control shutdown when power is lost. You would be better asking on https://forums.raspberrypi.com
